# Convert SQL Server 2008 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, converters

Is there a standard way, now that the MySQL migration toolkit is no longer supported, to transition a SQL Server database to MySQL.

I've tried running older versions of the Migration tool, but I keep getting java RE issues.  I installed JRE 5.0u8, but am still getting weird java issues (I suspect just due to the software not being updated).

I also tried exporting the data as CSV's, but SQL Server keeps spitting out ill-formed CSV's that MySQL can't import, and I have no idea why.  Just get duplicate primary key errors, even though when I grep the "bad" key, there is only one occurrence of it in the file.  And yes, I truncated the table before trying to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time, but eventually the csv method worked for me.  SQL Server was outputting some weird characters, I just had to track those down.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Migration tool is a old tool, but it can work.
You can use it to  create a file with your result SQL (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`s), and after export to file (not live migration), you can fix manualy some errors in the result.

Ugly.

Comment: How did you get MySQL Migration tool to work? I tried on Windows Server 2008 and Mac OS X Lion.  The Lion download didn't even have the migration tool.

Comment: Looks like the computer gods wer looking over you.  Never quite was that lucky.  Do you know which link you got the software from?